# Mac OS X script to change display resolution

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, script, resolution

Is it possible to change display resolution in Mac OS X?

If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in tool to do this, but some people have made their own.

[Newscreen](http://www.barbariangroup.com/posts/619-changing_screen_resolution_from_the_command_line_on_a_mac)

[setgetscreenres](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090413120929454)

Comment: Link for Newscreen is broken - the setgetscreenres links works and is a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

A command-line utility used by a large number of OS X enterprise administrators is [SetDisplay](https://github.com/magnusviri/SetDisplay).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040908141042786) from Macworld hint that show show to do this from AppleScript. You will have to install the [`csreen`](http://www.pyehouse.com/cscreen/) utility. I haven't tried this myself, so YMMV.